# changing the class when the button is clicked

Tags: javascript

it is necessary that when you click on the button, the 'active' class is removed from the first div, and added to the second. When pressed again, the active class was removed from the active block and added to the next one, and so on until the end

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="block active"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
<button class="next">Next</button>
```

```
.main {
  display: flex;
}

.block {
  width: 8px;
  height: 16px;
  background: #767676;
  margin: 5px;
}

.active {
  height: 26px;
}

.next {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```
const btn = document.querySelector('.next');
btn.addEventListener(`click`, e => {
 document.querySelectorAll(`.main > .block:not(.active)`)[0].classList += ` active`;
});
```

Comment: Please may you share the JS too?

Comment: @dxxdly Can you please share your current code that is trying to achieve this behavior? Stack Overflow is for helping with issues, not writing solutions for you.

Comment: I updated it, I only managed to add a class, I tried to do it through forEach, referring to index, but writes to me undefined   
@Gary Holiday

Answer (score 0):

This snippet should do the trick.

First, you remove the "active" class from all elements. Then you re-add the "active" class to the element which comes next.

```js
let currentIndex = 0;

const handleNext = () => {
  currentIndex++;
  const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("block");
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, elem => {
    elem.classList.remove("active")
   });
   
   if (currentIndex >= elements.length) return;
   elements[currentIndex].classList.add("active");
};
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
}

.block {
  width: 8px;
  height: 16px;
  background: #767676;
  margin: 5px;
}

.active {
  height: 26px;
}

.next {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="block active"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
<button class="next" onClick="handleNext()">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Please use the following javascript code:

```
    const btn = document.querySelector('.next');
    btn.addEventListener(`click`, e => {
        const currentActive = document.querySelector('.main > .block.active');
        let nextActive;
        if (currentActive === document.querySelector('.main').lastElementChild) {
            nextActive = document.querySelector('.main > .block:first-child');
        } else {
            nextActive = currentActive.nextElementSibling;
        }
        currentActive.classList.remove('active');
        nextActive.classList.add('active');
    });
```